# Cannot create Federated View

Tags: mysql, mariadb, view, federated-table

For the first time ever could not find a solution on internet! 
The problem is when I'm trying to (on local server):

```
CREATE TABLE `DB_1`.`testView`
ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='remote_server';
```

I'm getting an error:

> #1939 - Engine FEDERATED failed to discover table `DB_1`.`testView` with 'CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `testView` AS select 'test_line' AS `test_line` CONNECTION='remote_server''

Obviously you can see that VIEW is very simple for testing purposes (executed on remote server):

```
 CREATE VIEW `DB_1`.`testView` AS SELECT "test_line"
```

The user in `remote_server` has all privileges. View was tested with different options and content. Federated tables work fine. Server version on both machines: 10.0.29-MariaDB-0+deb8u1

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [FederatedX](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/federatedx-storage-engine/) engine and since you are not specifying column definitions explicitly, it is trying to perform [assisted discovery](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/table-discovery/#assisted-discovery) to retrieve the structure of the table. It cannot do it with the underlying "table" being a view, so you are getting the error.

Instead, try to specify the columns:

```
-- remote
CREATE VIEW `DB_1`.`testView` AS SELECT "test_line"

-- local
CREATE TABLE `DB_1`.`testView` (test_line varchar(16))
ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='remote_server';
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed that was exactly the reason! Additionally thanks for linking related manual! No idea how I haven't tried explicit column definiton!